# Kafka streams KTable recursive join

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a KTable with master data that I use to enrich the data coming on kafka topic. This master data is generated from a master_data table that is hierarchical i.e. master_data has parent and children of type master_data. Right now the code I use to join and enrich raw data with master data leaf node looks like this

```
final KStream<String, String> enrichedWithMasterData = rawData
            .leftJoin(masterTable,
                    (key, value) -> dataParser.getMasterCodeFromRawData(value), (rawData, masterData) -> {...}
```

How can I create a KStream by doing recursive joins untill I reach the root parent is reached. I want to enrich the raw data with all its master parents. The master_data hierarchy is dynamic which means there no fixed depth to the master_data tree, which means I can't write a static code with fixed number of statically defined KStreams.